# Duall Boot with two linux

Tags: dual-boot, fedora

Please give me full instrunction for dual boot of two linux one is ubuntu and second is fedora.
i like ubuntu but, also fedora
Thank you

Comment: There are manuals on this site and elsewhere. One thing you need to decide on is whether you'll want to hibernate the system. If not, the two distros can share the swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really straightforward process. First you install one of the distros, say Fedora. Then you install Ubuntu. Pay attention to the installation instructions, which will ask you if you want to wipe your hard drive or if you want to install the new operating system alongside the other one that's already installed (i.e., if you want to dual-boot).

In order to install Linux, make sure you have an installation media (CD, DVD or USB pendrive) and boot you system with this media inserted. You might have to configure your BIOS to boot from the disk or USB drive in order to trigger the installation procedure.